# KQL filter series by max value

Tags: time-series, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to make a timechart but my graph is littered by series which have not significant values:
[image]
Is it possible to filter series by:

1. Taking only a certain number of them with greatest max values
2. Discarding all series with max value < const

My request is

```
let Step = timespan(1d);
let PeriodStart = ago(30d);
cluster("").database("").table("")
    | where Timestamp > PeriodStart
    | where Source == "courierapp" and isnotempty(CourierId)
    | summarize by CourierId, bin(Timestamp, Step), AppVersion
    | make-series Version=count() default=0 on Timestamp from PeriodStart to ago(0d) step Step by AppVersion
    | render timechart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is based on [series_stats()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-statsfunction)

```
let threshold = 1000;
...  
| make-series Version=count() default=0 on Timestamp from PeriodStart to ago(0d) step Step by AppVersion
| extend series_stats(Version)
| where series_stats_Version_max >= threshold
| render timechart
```